How to use a key to stop playing the current animation, and replay it from the beginning?
In my Unity project, I tried to use a key to stop the current animation and immediately play it from the beginning again. I also tried to control the delay before I can press again.
The following coded is my current work, but I'm stuck on how to play the animation clip "Hit" from the start.
//Interrupt the Current animation and Replay from the beginning

else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)) 

 {
    if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Hit") != true) anim.Play("Hit");
    //Play Hit if not playing Hit
    else if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Hit") == true)
    //If playing Hit
   {
   //1.Stop the Current Animation Immediately, no delay

   //2.Repeat to play "Hit" from the beginning
   }
 }


What I want to achieve is the following function:

